Why do I get this browser alert? 'NoScript' started debugging this browser
Since a few days I'm getting this weird alert in my browser and I'd like to know why:
" 'NoScript' started debugging this browser "
(You can look at the first image I provided below for an example of what's happening.)
I'm using the Brave browser (based on Chrome/Chromium) and I have a couple of extensions, including NoScript. I've been using this browser with pretty much all the current extensions for a few years and never got any alert like this until a few days ago.
When I click the Cancel button this alert always come back after one or two hours after a completely random amount of time. It can range from a few seconds to multiple hours between alerts. I'm pretty sure I didn't change any configuration in the browser or in NoScript that could have caused this to happen. Maybe the NoScript extension got updated and the new version is causing this? I don't know... What do you think?
When I saw this for the first times I got a bit scared it was caused by some malware or something like that but I don't think it's the case, right? I searched on Google for this alert and I really couldn't find anything, not even a single little clue...
Anybody knows why do I get this Alert and how I could fix this?

By the way...
I found an option named "Debug" inside the "Advanced Settings". I never touched this, only clicked it once to see what it does exactly. It seems like it's only displaying a json file with all the policies in NoScript... so it's pretty clear to me it doesn't have anything to do with this alert.


Your best bet is to use the NoScript support forum.
